# convert rows to columns from select result

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4 and tb5

This the select query

```
SELECT c.code_chantier, f.lib_famille, SUM(a.pamp_art * l.qte_ligne) AS Total 
        FROM tb1 c

            JOIN tb2 b ON (c.id_chantier = b.chantier_id_chantier)
            JOIN tb3 l ON (b.id_brc = l.bon_reception_id_reception)
            JOIN tb4 a ON (l.article_id_article = a.id_article)
            JOIN tb5 f ON(a.famille_id_famille = f.id_famille) 
            AND b.type_brc = 2 

            GROUP BY c.code_chantier, f.lib_famille
            ORDER BY Total DESC
```

This the result of select query

```
    +---------------+------------------+--------------------+
| code_chantier | lib_famille      | Total              |
+---------------+------------------+--------------------+
| SC-16-23      | TRAVAUX SPECIAUX |            42600.5 |
| SC-16-15      | TRAVAUX SPECIAUX |            42006.5 |
| AJ-16-01      | PEINTURE         | 25018.779836090427 |
| MN-16-03      | PEINTURE         | 22441.573751561686 |
| AJ-16-01      | TRAVAUX SPECIAUX |          8604.6135 |
| SC-16-26      | TRAVAUX SPECIAUX |  7660.799999999999 |
| MN-16-04      | PEINTURE         |  6223.201931872805 |
| RA-16-12      | PEINTURE         |  6118.147946090509 |
| AM-16-01      | TRAVAUX SPECIAUX |  6021.484556962026 |
| CB-16-02      | TRAVAUX SPECIAUX |  5509.265642857144 |
```

Just iwant to display the occurrence of `lib_famille` in two columns `TRAVAUX SPECIAUX` and `PEINTURE`. For exemple the header of result table contains `| code_chantier |TRAVAUX | SPECIAUXPEINTURE | Total |`

Answer (score 1):

You can just select `lib_famille="TRAVAUX SPECIAUX"` to get a column with booleans that tell you if that was the value of that column. Arguably, this is not something you should do in your sql query, but instead in the script itself. This will only cause you to have to change things in two places when you decide to add another value to that column.

```
SELECT c.code_chantier, f.lib_famille="TRAVAUX SPECIAUX" AS "TRAVAUX SPECIAUX", f.lib_famille="PEINTURE" AS "PEINTURE", SUM(a.pamp_art * l.qte_ligne) AS Total
```